# Float data without fraction part

Tags: c, types

The make difference between double and float data, we add `f`. But when i tried to write:

```
float Value = 255f;
```

The compiler diplays the following error.:

```
  line 50: error (dcc:1633): parse error  near 'f'                    
  line 50: error (dcc:1206): syntax error                             
  line 50: fatal error (dcc:1340): can't recover from earlier errors
```

Why ?

Comment: What error is the compiler giving you?

Comment: Remember that the full name of the type is _floating point data_. You missed the point!

Comment: Interesting question, I didn't know this, since I always use the `period` and it turns out the standard forces it's usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to draft n1570, **§6.4.4.2**, paragraph **¶2**

> **Description**
>   A floating constant has a significand part that may be followed by an exponent part and a
>   suffix that specifies its type. The components of the significand part may include a digit
>   sequence representing the whole-number part, followed by a period (.), followed by a
>   digit sequence representing the fraction part. The components of the exponent part are an
>   e, E, p, or P followed by an exponent consisting of an optionally signed digit sequence.
>   Either the whole-number part or the fraction part has to be present; **for decimal floating
>   constants, either the period or the exponent part has to be present**.

I made the relevant part bold, so you can see why it doesn't work.

Note that this also implies that

```
float value = 255e0f;
```

works.

Answer (score 2):

You need a period in addition, in order the compiler to accept it:

```
float Value = 255.f;
```

It's part of the standard specification but I guess it was chosen this way in order to simplify the implementation of the lexical analyzer and also improve the readability of the number, since it's easy to think it's a hex number otherwise.

Comment: It doesn't simplify the lexical analyzer to any non-trivial degree.

Comment: @EJP If you were allowed to write *hexadecimal* floating-point literals with only a mantissa, there would be a genuine lexical ambiguity because 'f' is a hex digit.  (This isn't why the spec is how it is, though, since the 'f' suffix predates hexadecimal floating point literals.)

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you are missing a period in your code.

```
 float Value = 255.f;
```

Add a period before f and you should be good to go. If this doesn't work, please tell us what Error you're receiving.

Comment: The OP clearly states that the problem is the **lack** of the period, the question was why?

Comment: The compiler doesn't understand it if you don't add the period. It's just the proper way to type the code.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the compiler, it's the standard that specifies this, so the compiler is just compilant with the standard, but someone could write a compiler which doesn't care about this, note that you didn't specify which compiler requires this.